# React Native login federated AWS Facebook y Google

Tags: amazon-web-services, facebook, react-native, google-oauth, amazon-cognito

I tell you, at this moment I am trying to configure the deeplink on facebook and google, for a mobile application, the configuration of my deep links has been this on android, for react-native (It doesn't have EXPO):

```
 <intent-filter android:label="@string/app_name">
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <!-- Accepts URIs that begin with "http://www.federado.com/” -->
    <data android:scheme="http"
          android:host="www.federado.com"/>
    <!-- note that the leading "/" is required for pathPrefix-->
</intent-filter>
<intent-filter android:label="@string/app_name">
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <!-- Accepts URIs that begin with "federado://Profile/” -->
    <data android:scheme="federado"/>
    <!-- note that the leading "/" is required for pathPrefix-->
</intent-filter>
```

The problem I have had is that I am not sure how to establish the deep link on both Facebook and Google, since it is React Native with Cognito AWS. When I try to implement something like:

```
https://www.federado.com/
```

OR

```
federado://Profile/
```

I get errors, indicating that these domains are not valid.

On the other hand, the AWS login if it works correctly is taking this deeplink `federado://Profile/` concatenating it with a more complex URL that generates something like:

```
https://logingfederado45fa-455885fa-dev.auth.us-east-1.amazoncognito.com/login?response_type=code&client_id=7hslgua4jrsas&redirect_uri=federado://Profile/
```

So it occurred to me to use this in the domains requested by Facebook, but I still get these errors:

> The redirection failed because the URI is not included in the list of
>   authorized OAuth client applications. Check that the client and web
>   "OAuth" access is activated and add all the domains of your
>   applications as "OAuth" redirection URI

OR

> URL blocked: The redirection failed because the URI is not included in
>   the white list of the app's OAuth client configuration. Verify that
>   OAuth client access and OAuth web access are enabled, and add all
>   domains of the app as valid OAuth redirect URIs.

So if someone can explain to me what I should do to configure these domains I would be very grateful.

[Example I access with aws cognito](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EZsWE.gif)

[when I tried to access with cognito Facebook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d8NDl.gif)

[How I had configure Facebook](https://youtu.be/pEG16HTRv_A)

Comment: It looks like you are trying to combine the web login flow with an app-protocol link …? I don’t think that makes any sense to begin with. The app dashboard won’t even let you save that as a valid redirect URI.

Comment: Ajam, exact for this reason I say I don't know how I do the configure process in the facebook's control panel. What tipe of configuration I should make in the facebook and google platform?

Comment: If you want to implement the actual web login flow, then you need to use a HTTPS URL for your redirect_uri. And you need to input it in the Valid OAuth Redirect URIs field into the FB app settings, login section. The whole login flow has to happen in a browser / webview then.

Comment: Can I get the https domain from the cognito control panel or where is configured? because I still do not have a domain, and I imagine that somewhere I should to establish this deeplink "federated://Profile/" like does the AWS loging when I access.
This link is generated atomatically by cognito when I register to web and also is opens the screem "Profile" in the app:
https://logingfederado45fa-455885fa-dev.auth.us-east-1.amazoncognito.com/login?response_type=code&client_id=7hslgua4jrsas&redirect_uri=federado://Profile/

Comment: I put on a GIF where you can see how is found in this moment